# Alternative for sorting results based on script_metric aggregation in elasticsearch

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I want to sort my search result based on result of `script_metric` aggregation. but always I got error in response.
I search about that and I figure out this is a limitation in elasticsearch implementation. it's not possible sort based on `script_metric` aggregation field. 
**also, I have to paginate my result, because it's may there are many results.
so I can't retrieve all result and then sort results in code.**

I want to know if there is any good alternative for this case.
this is my query below

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "creationTimestamp": {
        "gte": 1475613000,
        "lte": 1475699400
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "messages_count": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "sourceId",
        "order": {
          "totalViews": "desc"
        },
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "totalViews": {
          "scripted_metric": {
            "init_script": "_agg['maximum'] = []",
            "map_script": "max = _source.histories[_source.histories.values.size()-1].views; _agg.maximum.add(max);",
            "combine_script": "sum = 0; for (m in _agg.maximum) { sum += m }; return sum;",
            "reduce_script": "sum = 0; for (a in _aggs) { sum += a }; return sum;"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

here the response of elasticsearch for my query:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "aggregation_execution_exception",
                "reason": "Invalid terms aggregation order path [totalViews]. Terms buckets can only be sorted on a sub-aggregator path that is built out of zero or more single-bucket aggregations within the path and a final single-bucket or a metrics aggregation at the path end."
            }
        ],
        "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
        "reason": "all shards failed",
        "phase": "query",
        "grouped": true,
        "failed_shards": [
            {
                "shard": 0,
                "index": "datacollection",
                "node": "PS0_HLzxRk-jO_C-_x8ivw",
                "reason": {
                    "type": "aggregation_execution_exception",
                    "reason": "Invalid terms aggregation order path [totalViews]. Terms buckets can only be sorted on a sub-aggregator path that is built out of zero or more single-bucket aggregations within the path and a final single-bucket or a metrics aggregation at the path end."
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": 500
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution my self. I read this elasticsearch document [page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html) and I found an alternative for `script_metric` aggregation. so change inner aggregation and everything is fine and work great.

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "creationTimestamp": {
        "gte": 1475613000,
        "lte": 1475699400
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "messages_count": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "sourceId",
        "order": {
          "totalViews": "desc"
        },
        "size" : 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "totalViews": {
          "sum": {<---- using sum aggregation instead of script_metric, and write my previous script just like this
            "script": "_source.histories[_source.histories.values.size()-1].views"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```